# Changing text inside of shapes

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to search a sheet with shapes containing text that match the "A" column and then to change it to the corresponding "B" column. I wish to do so with multiple shapes. I have linked to a simplified version of the [sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1UHZ.png)
I will be working on:

```
Sub linkCell()


For i = 1 To 3
    For j = 1 To 3
        If ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & j).Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Value = "=B" & j
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is faithful to your vision:

```
Sub linkCell()
    Dim s As Shape, r As Range
    For Each r In [a1:a3]
        For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If r = s.TextFrame.Characters.Caption Then
                s.OLEFormat.Object.Formula = "=" & r(, 2).Address
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```